# elasticsearch ngram and postgresql trigram search results are not match

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, similarity, n-gram, sentence-similarity

I've crereated an index on **elasticsearch** same as bellow:

```
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "trigrams_filter": {
                        "type":     "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 3,
                        "max_gram": 3
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "trigrams": {
                        "type":      "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter":   [
                            "lowercase",
                            "trigrams_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
    }
},
"mappings": {
    "issue": {
        "properties": {
            "description": {
                "type":     "string",
                "analyzer": "trigrams"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test items are bellow:

```
"alici onay verdi basarili satisiniz gerceklesti diyor ama hesabima para transferi gerceklesmemis"

"otomatik onay işlemi gecikmiş"

"************* nolu iade islemi urun kargoya verilmedi zamaninda iade islemlerinde urun erorr hata veriyor"
```

I've test  this index with bellow query:

```
GET issue/_search
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
            "description":{
                 "query": "otomatik onay istemi zamaninda gerceklesmemis"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

And result:

```
{
      ....
      "hits": {
            ....
                "max_score": 2.3507352,
                "hits": [
                          {
                              ....                                   
                              "_score": 2.3507352,
                              "_source": {
                                   "issue_id": "*******",
                                   "description": "alici onay verdi basarili satisiniz gerceklesti diyor ama hesabima para transferi gerceklesmemis"
                                          }
                           }
                        ]
                }
 }
```

But same data on **postgresql** with bellow SQL response another result:

```
SELECT 
     public.tbl_issue_descriptions_big.description,
     similarity(description, 'otomatik onay islemi zamaninda gerceklesmemis') AS sml
FROM
     public.tbl_issue_descriptions_big
WHERE
     description %'otomatik onay islemi zamaninda gerceklesmemis'
ORDER BY
     sml DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Result is:

```
description                                           | sml
======================================================|======
otomatik onay islemi gecikmis                         |0,351852
```

Why is this difference caused?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I am curious, I find PostgreSQL more accurate out of the box.

Comment: No, I didn't solve the problem. Because Postgresql calculating via tf/idf similarity machanism but ElasticSearch using BM25. May be you can change similarity mechanism on ElasticSearch. But don't on Postgresql. 
May be you can use thirty party pgPLSQL function or Python.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know enough about postgres to give a qualified answer there (as this also depends on the documents that are indexed and if they scoring formulas are exactly the same, which I doubt), but Elasticsearch has an [explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-explain.html) and an [explain parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-request-explain.html) in the search, that help you to find out why a certain document was scored this way.

Comment: Thanks your answer. 
But I think explain postgresql equvalent  is ts_vector and used for full text search. But ngram and similarity using for machine learning. I'm searching similarity algoritms on elasticsearch now.

Comment: check out the lucene documentation, like https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html or https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html (which is default since ES 5.0 if you create a new index)